# Clojure manipulate sequence of strings

Tags: vector, clojure, reduce

I have a data structure of the form `["a" "b" " c" "d" " e" " f" "g"]`

I'd like to reduce that to `["a" "b c" "d e f" "g"]`, that is, strings that begin with a space are joined to the one preceding them.

I've been struggling with it for a couple of hours, and am looking for some inspiration!

Comment: show us what you got so far

Comment: I got as far as realising that I needed to use reduce, and then hit a bit of a brick wall. These initial answers are all very creative, so I'll have a play with them before selecting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybrid approach where the filter and the initial accumulator handle the first starts with a space case.

```
(defn join-when-space [vs]
  (mapv (partial apply str) 
    (filter not-empty 
      (reduce (fn [a s] (if (re-find #"^\s" s) 
                          (conj (pop a) (conj (peek a) s)) 
                          (conj a [s]))) 
         [[]] vs))))
```

Comment: Thanks A. Webb. All responses were creative, performance wise all were indistinguishable on my mac, but I preferred your economy of characters. Hardly a responsible metric, but there you go!

Answer (score 2):

This splits the string sequence into blocks, then joins all groups of strings which should be joined with a single `string/join` call per group, so it avoids the quadratic behaviour of solutions pastings strings together one by one:

```
(def xs ["a" "b" " c" "d" " e" " f" "g"])

(require '[clojure.string :as string])

(->> xs
     (partition-by #(.startsWith ^String % " "))
     (map vec)
     (partition-all 2)
     (reduce (fn [acc [ps ss]]
               (-> acc
                   (into (pop ps))
                   (conj (string/join "" (cons (peek ps) ss)))))
             []))
;= ["a" "b c" "d e f" "g"]
```

Note that this assumes that the first string does not start with a space. To do away with this assumption, you could prepend an empty string (`(cons "" xs)` instead of `xs` in the above, or `(cons "")` as the first `->>` step) to "catch" them. In that case the result would either start with a string resulting from joining together the sequence-initial strings starting with spaces or an empty space if the sequence does not start with such strings, so you can check for the presence of `""` at the first position in the result and possibly filter it out.

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way of doing it using `reduce`, although there's probably a more elegant way of doing the same thing - there often is in Clojure :)

```
(defn join-when-space [v]
   (->> (reduce (fn [acc next-value]
                   (if (re-matches #"^ .*" next-value)
                     (concat (butlast acc) [(str (last acc) next-value)])
                     (concat acc [next-value]))) 
                [[] (first v)] (rest v))
         rest
         (into [])))
```

Comment: Same idea, bit cleaner: `(reduce (fn [a s] (if (re-find #"^\s" s) (conj (pop a) (str (peek a) s)) (conj a s))) [] ["a" "b" " c" "d" " e" " f" "g"])`

Answer (score 0):

This function produces a lazy sequence of the sequence *strings* spliced on initial spaces:

```
(defn spliced-seq [strings]
  (let [[x & xs] strings]
   (if (empty? xs)
    [x]
    (let [[ys & ns] (split-with #(.startsWith % " ") xs)]
      (cons (apply str x ys) (lazy-seq (f ns)))))))
```

Then `(vec (spliced-seq) ["a" " b" " c" "d" "e"]))` produces `["a b c" "d e"]`.